# Representing mathematical relations in Alloy

Tags: alloy

I am new to Alloy and I am still quite confused. I am relatively comfortable with mathematical relations but not sure how to translate those to Alloy.

Say I have the following definition of a (mathematical) relation

```
rel = {(x, y) | x \in S1, y \in S2}
```

Is the following Alloy fragment a correct representation for 'rel'?

```
sig S2 {}

sig S1 {rel: S2}
```

How would I constrain this relation to be irreflexive and transitive?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your model defines `rel` to be a relation between the sets `S1` and `S2`. To constrain the relation you could write something like that:

```
fact antireflexive { no iden & rel }
```

That is, there's no element mapped to itself in `rel`

And

```
fact transitive { rel = ^rel }
```

Meaning that `rel` is equal to its transitive closure and therefore transitive.

Comment: Having looked at your fragment again I've noticed that you have constrained your relation such that it maps each element in S1 to exactly one element in S2, if you want it to be an unrestricted relation you should write `rel:set S2`

Comment: Thanks for reply. This helps

Answer (score 0):

First define the types:

```
 sig S1, S2 {}
```

Then you can define a `rel` relation with the following equivalent syntaxes

```
let rel = { x : univ, y : univ | x in S1 and y in S2 }
let rel = { x : S1, y : S2 }
let rel = S1 -> S2
```